# What are the pros and cons of getting a radon inspection before buying a home?

Tags: inspection, radon

Discussion I have had with some of my partners.   We understand what radon is, what causes it, how to mitigate it and the health effects it imposes.   These are givens and a different question.

My question is if we are buying a house as-is, 90% this is the case.   Why would we pay for a radon inspection that runs between $150 when you can get a reliable reader for around $150 and just install it in the basement?

(other givens is that the house had a prior radon inspection done on it and the house is an area of low to moderate radon issues)

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason I think a professional radon inspection might be worth paying for, in the context of buying a house, is that if radon is found, you'll get a thorough report by a professional that explains where and why radon was found, an estimate for the cost of mitigations, and the risks of not doing that.  This then becomes a negotiation tool to get the seller to pay for the costs of radon mitigation, or to reduce the selling price accordingly.  Just because you understand all of these things doesn't mean the seller will, but a report from a neutral third party may be very helpful in convincing them.

You might be able to accomplish the same thing with a DIY radon detector, but if the seller doesn't understand that it's a big deal, and doesn't want to knock thousands off the selling price just because you brought over a box that beeped, then you might need to go the professional route.

All of this, of course, is assuming you have the skills and knowledge to install and use that $150 radon detector effectively, and that it will be as sensitive as professional tools are.  This may be true for you, but it's definitely not true for most homebuyers, so it makes sense that a professional radon inspection is recommended to most people.

Comment: Radon tools now give your readings and explain them and in context to ranges and even graph out levels over hours/days.     Sorry but giving a downvote because that is not how it works.   They don't dispute me.   I am a buyer and any findings that I present to the home owner have to be on the disclosure by law.   The only way around it is for the HOME OWNER to have the radon test done and prove that my readings were inaccurate.   I agree with everything else but this part is super misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If the radon test is positive, you may be able to get the seller to pay for all or part of radon mitigation.

I just made this mistake -- agreed to buy as-is before the test.  Did the test anyway and it came back about twice the recommended maximum level of radon.  I should have waited the 5 days for the test to come back.  Would've been able to get the seller to pay $1000-$2000 instead of buying that myself.  Not a disaster but money I could've saved.

Comment: Yea I get that but these are houses sold as-is.   I am not getting the seller to reduce based on this small cost.   Also does having a radon test done by a professional differ from a good home monitoring system?

Answer (score 0):

With an as is sale it would be a waste in my opinion.

I would say I might consider having the test if the area was known for radon issues.

My last 2 home purchases I have not had radon tests done but the one prior to that I did as it was in an area known for issues and the abatement system was not all there. But again I was able to get the pump and testing paid for it was not as is.

Comment: This is one of those home things that I think might have just become outdated.   Why not install a wireless kit for $150 vs paying a company to measure it.   I would need to see evidence that a professional company offers more accurate readings.   My gut tells me that a company selling the monitors is more on the hook for mess ups in readings than your average local radon inspectors - and I have no idea what equipment they are using.    I see how this was important 10-20 years ago but not now.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you like to gamble.

Simple remediation may not be worth the cost of a professional test. However, we had to breakout slabs and install pipes down in the ground, connect all the pipes together, and then install a pipe up through roof in the garage with an exhaust fan always running. Cost was $$$$$.

I wish we could have used that cost to reduce the purchase price.

Btw, once the seller knows of the condition, they must disclose it to you...even if it’s sold “as is”.

How often do you go to Las Vegas?